# Is it possible to set different value for every selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

My question is simple. Is it possible to set the different value for every selector? In my real project code, I'm doing it like this.

```
$("#zero").on("click", function() {
  pressNumButton('0');
});

$("#one").on("click", function() {
  pressNumButton('1');
});
```

Yes, I know one solution to this problem. I could use the same class for every number the user pressed and then get the value of it because every id `#zero` - `#nine` has the value of 0 - 9. Is it possible to do it using IDs?

Is using classes the best solution here?

---

I've commented out some lines in my snippet so you can understand it better.

```js
// It should display One for first selector, and Two for the second one
//$('#one, #two').text('One');

// In other words, how can I do this job with a one-liner? I know I can do it with multiple lines but the problem I have many selectors, not just two. It's just an example
$('#one').text('One');
$('#two').text('Two');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to simplify the logic you could create an object, which is keyed by the `id` attributes of the elements and has the values their text should be set to. Then you can use a single event handler on all element instances. Something like this:

```js
var content = {
  one: 'Text A...',
  two: 'Text B...'
}

$('.foo').click(function() {
  $(this).text(content[this.id]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo" id="one">click me</div>
<div class="foo" id="two">click me</div>
```

This can be simplified further if needed by using a plain array and associating the elements by their indexes. However this is more brittle and can be broken simply by amending your HTML, which id why I'd recommend using the object with id keys instead.

Comment: Thank you, but it means I have to use classes?

Comment: Yes. If you want to genericise your logic you should be using them anyway to group elements. You could select by DOM structure instead though, if preferred, eg. `$('#parentElement > div')`

Comment: But in this particular situation, what do you think, is it better to use your solution or this? Because value and argument can be concatenated.  https://jsfiddle.net/2r4a2zeq/

Comment: If that's your goal then you can just pass the value without the need for the object lookup - but then I don't see how your example snippet is in any way relevant to this?

Comment: I posted a simpler example, the jsFiddle, I posted the link to, is a real-project example.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to store the values in the object as @Rory suggested in his answer then you can do it like this

```js
$('.foo').click(function() {
  $(this).text("Number " + $(this).attr("id"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo" id="one">click me</div>
<div class="foo" id="two">click me</div>
```

Comment: This is assuming the `id` and text values can be concatenated. I got the impression from the OP that they only simplified their example in this way and the real use case is that the values are completely different.

Comment: Thank you, so now I understand to make it simple and group elements I have to use classes.